# Spring Boot (1.3.5) - Default Error View

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-web

I'm using Spring Boot (v1.3.5.RELEASE). And in the docs, there's [this short section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling) regarding error-handling:

> Spring Boot provides an **/error** mapping by default that handles all errors in a sensible way, and it is registered as a ‘global’ error page in the servlet container. For machine clients it will produce a JSON response with details of the error, the HTTP status and the exception message. For browser clients there is a ‘whitelabel’ error view that renders the same data in HTML format (to customize it just add a View that resolves to ‘error’).

So, to set my own custom page, I'd just need a view that resolves to `error`. I've added Freemarker to my classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And sure enough, making a file named `error.ftl` in `src/main/resources/templates` did the job of getting me my own custom page.

However, instead of having `error.ftl` in the `resources/templates` folder, I'd like to place it inside `WEB-INF/templates`.

So, I moved the file (now in `WEB-INF/templates/error.ftl`) and made the following spring configuration-related beans:

```
@Bean(name = "freeMarkerViewResolver")
public FreeMarkerViewResolver getFreeMarkerViewResolver() {
    FreeMarkerViewResolver freeMarkerViewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    freeMarkerViewResolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
    return freeMarkerViewResolver;
}

@Bean(name = "freemarkerConfigurer")
public FreeMarkerConfigurer getFreeMarkerConfigurer() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPaths(
            "classpath:/templates/",
            "/WEB-INF/templates/");
    return freeMarkerConfigurer;
}
```

But now, I only get the whitelabel page instead of `/WEB-INF/templates/error.ftl` (when, let's say for example, I access an invalid path such as `localhost:8080/invalid`). Is there anything I missed?

I'm pretty sure `BasicErrorController` handles the job:

```
@RequestMapping(produces = "text/html")
public ModelAndView errorHtml(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setStatus(getStatus(request).value());
    Map<String, Object> model = getErrorAttributes(request,
            isIncludeStackTrace(request, MediaType.TEXT_HTML));
    return new ModelAndView("error", model);
}
```

And here are my logs:

```
2016-09-12 08:46:00.241 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@11e1fd30
2016-09-12 08:46:00.241 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/invalid]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.242 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@75739a6e] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-09-12 08:46:00.242 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : No handler mapping found for [/invalid]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.242 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@67eec602] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-09-12 08:46:00.242 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /invalid
2016-09-12 08:46:00.243 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/invalid]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.244 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping@605d8da4] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-09-12 08:46:00.244 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : No handler mapping found for [/invalid]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.244 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@3fa90efa] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-09-12 08:46:00.244 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/invalid] are [/**]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.244 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/invalid] are {}
2016-09-12 08:46:00.244 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/invalid] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@16545fd3]]] and 1 interceptor
2016-09-12 08:46:00.244 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@5ef1fb8a]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.244 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter@781974d0]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.244 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/invalid] is: -1
2016-09-12 08:46:00.244 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Applying "invalid path" checks to path: invalid
2016-09-12 08:46:00.244 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Resolving resource for request path "invalid"
2016-09-12 08:46:00.244 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Checking location: ServletContext resource [/]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.244 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : No match for location: ServletContext resource [/]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.244 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Checking location: class path resource [META-INF/resources/]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.245 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : No match for location: class path resource [META-INF/resources/]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.245 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Checking location: class path resource [resources/]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.245 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : No match for location: class path resource [resources/]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.245 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Checking location: class path resource [static/]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.245 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : No match for location: class path resource [static/]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.245 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Checking location: class path resource [public/]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.245 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : No match for location: class path resource [public/]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.245 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : No matching resource found - returning 404
2016-09-12 08:46:00.245 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-09-12 08:46:00.246 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@11e1fd30
2016-09-12 08:46:00.246 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2016-09-12 08:46:00.246 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@292356a6
2016-09-12 08:46:00.246 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.246 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@75739a6e] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-09-12 08:46:00.246 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : No handler mapping found for [/error]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.246 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@67eec602] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-09-12 08:46:00.246 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2016-09-12 08:46:00.247 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Found 2 matching mapping(s) for [/error] : [{[/error],produces=[text/html]}, {[/error]}]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.248 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.248 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@5ef1fb8a]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.248 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
2016-09-12 08:46:00.248 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Invoking [BasicErrorController.errorHtml] method with arguments [org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@292356a6, org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade@4fa94295]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.248 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Method [errorHtml] returned [ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'error'; model is {timestamp=Mon Sep 12 08:46:00 SGT 2016, status=404, error=Not Found, message=No message available, path=/invalid}]
2016-09-12 08:46:00.249 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, text/html;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [text/html])
2016-09-12 08:46:00.249 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@58edc30] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2016-09-12 08:46:00.249 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@58edc30] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-09-12 08:46:00.249 TRACE 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@292356a6
2016-09-12 08:46:00.249 DEBUG 5888 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redefining the freemarker beans (which may be the cause of your error), you could use spring-boot's property `spring.freemarker.template-loader-path`, as described [**here**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/):

> If you use FreeMarker you will also have a FreeMarkerViewResolver with
>   id ‘freeMarkerViewResolver’. It looks for resources in a loader path
>   (externalized to **spring.freemarker.templateLoaderPath**, default
>   ‘classpath:/templates/’) by surrounding the view name with a prefix
>   and suffix (externalized to spring.freemarker.prefix and
>   spring.freemarker.suffix, with empty and ‘.ftl’ defaults
>   respectively). It can be overridden by providing a bean of the same
>   name.

The default is this:

```
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=classpath:/templates/ # Comma-separated list of template paths.
```

You could add this to your application.properties:

```
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=classpath:/WEB-INF/templates/
```

Comment: Certainly another good way of configuring Freemarker in Spring, but my problem remains unsolved. Thank you for your input, though!

Comment: I just thought it could also solve the issue, just with the fact that you didn't redefine freemarker's bean (which could the source of the issue).

Comment: Ah. Yes, yes. I see your point; it's a valid suggestion. Thank you! (Also, there may be beginners out there, so, I'd like to point out that my folder is `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates` so, in @Alex's suggestion, I'd use `spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=/WEB-INF/templates/`.